# Why are changes made to my PATH variable not reflecting in the working path?

Tags: java

I am trying to set my java_home to java6 in my windows 8 machine, but java -version still shows java7. 
I checked the path using "path" in command line and the result does not show any changes that I had made to the variable.

Comment: see this tutorial https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
and this http://java-buddy.blogspot.gr/2012/01/set-path-for-jdk-7-on-windows-8.html.

Comment: This is a general Windows 8 issue, and not really a Java issue: You set a variable, and the change is not taking effect in subsequently launched `cmd` windows.  See http://superuser.com/questions/593949/why-wont-my-windows-8-command-line-update-its-path .

Answer (score 2):

If you have set the `PATH` properly then just re-launch the command prompt. Changes to PATH does not reflect in already opened command prompt.

Btw, java home variable should be in uppercase and with an underscore between the two words i.e `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Check my edit about the uppercase and underscore in JAVA_HOME

Comment: I'm aware of that... This seems to be an unusual behavior that I haven't experienced before.

Comment: Was struggling from long....needed to re-launch the command prompt for new PATH to reflect in the command prompt. Thanks.