# Java path not getting reflected even after changing the PATH variable when working with multiple java versions

Tags: java

When I am working with multiple versions of Java in my windows machine - 1.6 & 1.7, and when I try to switch from 1.7 to 1.6, and modified the PATH environment variable, it's still showing the 1.7 version only. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you also changed the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: After changing the path, you need to re-launch the command prompt. See..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839819/why-are-changes-made-to-my-path-variable-not-reflecting-in-the-working-path

Comment: "it's still showing..." What is still showing? How do you modify the PATH? And then how to you check the version?

Answer (score 8):

Java installations on Windows machines also copy a `java.exe` file into the directory `C:\Windows\System32` (as well as a `javaw.exe` and a `javaws.exe`).

As this directory is usually also part of the `PATH` environment variable and - also usually  - is mentioned before any program directory, you will see the output of the `java.exe` file that is from the system directory.

The path usually looks like:

> PATH = [...];C:\Windows\System32;[...];C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin;[...]

So even if you switch it to

> PATH = [...];C:\Windows\System32;[...];C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6\bin;[...]

you will get a "Version 7" output on the console. If you instead change your path variable to

> PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6\bin;[...];C:\Windows\System32;[...]

then you will get the "Version 6" output.

Comment: for me it was "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"

Comment: @iamgr007 Have a look at the date. It was back to 2014! The behavior of Java installations on Windows systems changed since then.

Comment: yeah I understand! just updating for the peeps looking into this now...

Answer (score 3):

In my case the files are copied to the below folder
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
and both the paths are appended in the system path.

removing the above paths from the system path and setting did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Always pay attention to the neatness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of registry in Windows cause the java executable uses the Windows Registry to locate the default version of Java to run. (registry > JAVA_HOME). If you want to switch between Java dont make installation but only unpacking zip and setting the JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, changing the environment variable values only is not sufficient enough to work with.
Look for java.exe & javaw.exe files in the Windows/System32 folder. Replace them with those files of the java version bin folder you are actually willing to switch and check the version now.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of these places to run from :

1. Eclipse :It is easy if using eclipse.(refer google :) )
2. if using command prompt(windows) i would suggest set path vairable for each command prompt i.e. do this :

   e:\somepath> set path=.;c:\pathto\JAVA_HOME\bin

for every CMD instance.

now lets say i have 1.5, 1.6 1.7 installed on my system then i would open three CMDs and issue the above commands for each installations (1.5, 1.6 and 1.7). now i have path variable pointing to my respective jdk installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. Using this command, `where java` from cmd we can get the java.exe path locations. Removing the java.exe for the old java version resolved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

check with set command to see where JAVA_HOME is pointing to...